# Force database Initialization with docker and postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, shell

I have a docker compose file for postgres database:

```
version: "3.8"
name: postgresdb-blue
services:
  # environnement postgresql
  postgresdb-blue:
    build:
      context: ./db
      shm_size: '60gb'
    container_name: postgresdb-blue
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "postgres", "-U", "root" ]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: db
    networks:
      - postgres-network
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    expose:
      - '5432'
    volumes:
      - ./db/setup/init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      # we can access data stored in volumes
      - ./db/dbstore/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/dbstore/postgres/files:/var/lib/postgresql/files

  pgAdmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    container_name: pgAdmin-blue
    restart: always
    user: root
    links:
      - postgresdb-blue
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb-blue
    networks:
      - postgres-network
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: root@root.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    volumes:
       - ./db/dbstore/postgres/pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin4/storage
       - ./db/setup/pgadmin4.db:/pgadmin4.db
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c "cp /pgadmin4.db /var/lib/pgadmin4/storage/pgadmin4.db && cd /pgadmin4 && /entrypoint.sh"


networks:
  postgres-network:

volumes:
  databases:
```

I also have a docker file in db folder:

```
FROM postgres:latest

WORKDIR /srv/sirene/
RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && apt-get install -y unzip \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/data/

EXPOSE 5432
```

I also have to download csv files from external source, so I created sh files to retrieve my CSV to import.

Here is a sample of file named 00-get-legal-units.csv

```
printf "RETRIEVING LEGAL UNITS DATA\n--------------------------------------\n"
mkdir -p /var/lib/postgresql/files
cd /var/lib/postgresql/files && wget  -o https://.../file.zip
cd /var/lib/postgresql/files && unzip -o file.zip

psql -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $POSTGRES_DB -c "CREATE TABLE table 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    property1 CHARACTER VARYING,
    property2 CHARACTER VARYING,
    property3 CHARACTER VARYING,
    ...
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;"

psql -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $POSTGRES_DB -c "COPY table(property1,property1,property1) FROM '/var/lib/postgresql/files/file.csv' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8';"
psql -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $POSTGRES_DB -c "CREATE INDEX table_index ON table(property1);"
```

My issues are the followings:
If i restart my container, I'd like to have the possibility to re run the whole setup depending on conditions:

1. the csv are stored in a volume and I want to reupload everything every month
2. i want to replay my table creation and data import too

Actually, if my database already exists, the initialization process is avoided...
To rerun everything, i have to delete manually the folder containing data ...
A second issue is converning shell files: the first file only is executed. I could put everything in a single file, but for more readability, i'd prefer split everything onto separate files.

Comment: I'd run these commands separately from the database initialization.  Does your application framework have a database migration system?  That would be the best place to do things like `CREATE TABLE`, you can incrementally re-run migrations, and it's not specifically tied to Docker.

Comment: At this stage, the main goal is to create a postgresql database with data from internet. It will also have a back end framework that will handle queries. I'll think about this alternative too...